# "in my daily life" or "on a daily basis"(hobbies context)

Tags: phrase-usage

I'm checking if it's possible to say the expression "in my daily life" in this context about hobbies:

> I like doing an average of 15 minutes exercise every morning, along with two additional one-hour sessions twice a week. That is very important for my health and helps me keep active in my daily life.

Comment: “In my day-to-day life” would probably be more idiomatic than “in my daily life”, at least in UK English.

Answer (score 1):

“in my daily life” means you have worked it into your other normal daily activities. In the context of exercise, this might mean things like always taking the stairs instead of the elevator, walking or cycling instead of taking a train/bus/car, etc.

“on a daily basis” means you do it (nearly) every day. This sounds more appropriate for exercise that is a specific part of your daily routine.